# ANDROID HttpURLConnection always uses GET

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I am developing an app in android studio and for web service calls I use `HttpURLConnection`. Although the class always uses `GET` when I call it, even tough I set it to `POST`. I have even double sat it to `POST` to make sure that's the method it will use.

```
URL url = new URL(Activity.this.getString(R.string.ws));
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
urlConn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConn.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
urlConn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
urlConn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + fileHelper.getPropertyFromSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.key_token)));
urlConn.connect();
```

Anyone else has had this problem before? And how to fix it?

PS. I have also tried OKHTTP, but still the same problem

**EDIT:**

I have found out the reason that the method will always be GET, is because when I call `setDoOutput` it doesn't change the value, not even if I do

```
urlConn.setDoOutput(!urlConn.getDoOutput);
```

Comment: can you show your complete method how you are calling your webservice

Comment: How do you know that it is always using GET?  Please add the full relevant code.  Note also that if you're hitting a web service and it does not define a POST option, then the request may be defaulting to GET.

Comment: @VivekMishra I have now edited the code within.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can see while debugging what method is used for the call. The webservice does provide the POST option and is tested in PostMan, where it works just fine

Comment: You are not passing any parameter in it ?

Comment: @VivekMishra I am writing a DataOutputStream after with the body in it

Comment: I worked with Android quite a bit, and with `HttpURLConnection` using `POST`, and I've never encountered this.  My finger is pointing at your PostMan setup at the moment.  Meaning, I think the Android code _is_ using POST, but it's not being received properly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, so by that you think I should check the format in which I am sending my parameters?

Comment: Is there anything else you can hit besides PostMan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `urlConn.connect();`. Use `urlConn.getOutputStream()` instead.

Comment: May I ask what this is doing differently?

Comment: `setDoOutput(true)` means you can post something rather than you are posting something. Once `urlConn.getOutputStream()` is called, the connection starts to output. That's the real post action. While `urlConn.connect()` don't have the meaning to output or post something.